# When antimatter meets matter do the two of them cancel eachother out?

Tags: science-based, technology, science-fiction, physics, weapons

I’ve designed melee weapons akin to lightsabers for my setting that emit a blade made out of antimatter. The handle itself serves as a mini particle accelerator, and it emits a magnetic field to contain the antimatter before releasing some. If the blade of this antimatter weapon made contact with normal matter, would it result in an explosion or delete the matter or what?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs of the physics stack.

Comment: It would result in an explosion, but what has this to do with world building?

Answer (score 2):

A magnetic field is effective at keeping away only moving charges. Most of the matter we have around us is in neutral state.

Being one meter away from a strong source of gamma ray is a pretty effective way to commit suicide, something similar to how Slotin died in the [demon's core accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_core#Second_incident)

> The standard protocol was to use shims between the halves, as allowing them to close completely could result in the instantaneous formation of a critical mass and a lethal power excursion. Under Slotin's own unapproved protocol, the shims were not used and the only thing preventing the closure was the blade of a standard straight screwdriver manipulated in Slotin's other hand.
>
> On the day of the accident, Slotin's screwdriver slipped outward a fraction of an inch while he was lowering the top reflector, allowing the reflector to fall into place around the core. Instantly there was a flash of blue light and a wave of heat across Slotin's skin; the core had become supercritical, releasing an intense burst of neutron radiation estimated to have lasted about a half second. Slotin quickly twisted his wrist, flipping the top shell to the floor. The heating of the core and shells stopped the criticality within seconds of its initiation, while Slotin's reaction prevented a recurrence and ended the accident. The position of Slotin's body over the apparatus also shielded the others from much of the neutron radiation, but he received a lethal dose of 1,000 rad (10 Gy) neutron and 114 rad (1.14 Gy) gamma radiation in under a second and died nine days later from acute radiation poisoning.

Comment: So the "demon core" wasn't actually demonic at all, it was just being operated by an idiot? Huh. You really do learn something new every day.

Comment: @F1Krazy, never underestimate the power of stupidity

Answer (score 0):

Explosion.  When matter and antimatter touch, they annihilate each other, and turn into pure energy.  Gamma rays mostly.

Comment: Since the antimatter is contained in a magnetic field, wouldn’t the explosion be only within the magnetic field? Matter would enter the field and make contact with the antimatter.

Comment: Yes, wherever matter meets antimatter, both explode.

Comment: Forget about swords touching, as soon as the antimatter weapon touches air, the resulting explosion will make you forget about swordfighting all together.

Comment: Real question tho: What if someone fired an antimatter bullet. Would it reach its target, or would the air molecules create such energetic explosions that the whole thing vaporized beforehand? - I want to ask physics SE, but they take a dim view of silly questions.

Comment: It won't even make it out the barrel of the gun.  There's probably normal matter air in the barrel.

Comment: @SurprisedDog How would you even ensure that the bullet doesn't touch air before being shot?